# Why is 0.0 == 0.0 false in REPL but true when executing natively?

Tags: floating-point, ocaml

`0.0 == 0.0` is `false` when I execute that expression in the interactive REPL:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.3

# 0.0 == 0.0;;
- : bool = false
# 0.0 = 0.0;;
- : bool = true
```

But it's `true` if I compile and run this program:

```
let _ =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  print_endline (string_of_bool (0.0 == 0.0));
  print_endline (string_of_bool (0.0 = 0.0))
```

dune file:

```
(executable (name main))
```

Compiling and running it:

```
$ dune --version
1.0.0
$ dune exec ./main.exe
true
true
```

How could `0.0 == 0.0` ever be `false`, and why would it be a different value when executing this code natively?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note for OCaml beginners: the "normal" equality is `=`. The `==` operator tests if two value have the same memory address.

The `==` operator is sometimes quite hard to understand. To quote the OCaml manual:

> On non-mutable types, the behavior of ( == ) is implementation-dependent; however, it is guaranteed that `e1 == e2` implies `compare e1 e2 = 0`.

`float` being a non-mutable type, there is no guarantee of its behavior on two equal values.

Now, let's see exactly what happens.

In the case of the interpreter, your expressions are evaluated without much optimization. The point is to put your code to execution quickly, not to have your code run fast. So when it sees a `0.0` constant, the programs allocates a new physical memory block that contains the appropriate data "float `0.0`". Allocate the same constant two times and you get two different memory addresses. Hence a `0.0 == 0.0` returns `false`

Now the native code compiler is much more smarter. It tries to minimize memory usage and execution time. When it sees that the same immutable constant is allocated two times, it considers "there is no point in allocating the same thing twice, let's allocate once".

In a way, the compiler turns `0.0 == 0.0` in `let c = 0.0 in c == c`. This is why you get `true`.

Comment: I also noticed that `0 == 0` returns true in both the repl and compiled code. Are floats stored differently than ints in ocaml?

Comment: Ints are stored differently than pretty much everything else. They are stored by value instead of being stored by reference. Hence `==` and `=` are the same operator on integers.

Comment: Ints are not the only thing stored by value. Variant constructors without arguments, [] and chars are too. Basically anything that fits in 31bit (or 63 bit on 64bit cpus) leaving 1 bit to mark something as being stored by value or by reference. Floats in ocaml are 64bit so they can't be stored by value.